# Where does xfce4-notes store data?

Tags: xfce, xubuntu, notes

I have a lot of xfce-notes groups containing each a lot of text. I want to transfert them to a new machine without copying the whole home directory.
Where does xfce4-notes store its data and configation files?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The notes are stored as text files in [`$XDG_DATA_HOME/notes/`](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-notes-plugin) (`~/.local/share/notes` by default).

The settings are in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/xfce4` (`~/.config/xfce4/xfce4-notes.*`).

Comment: Possible source: http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-notes-plugin#usage