# Where does xfce4-screenshooter save by default?

Tags: xfce, defaults, screenshot, user-default

I did a screenshot and also saved it, but I'm unable to figure out where it is. Looking into [the official docs](https://docs.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-screenshooter/usage) didn't tell me more and I also didn't find something quickly searching both the SE network and the whole internet. So this Q/A might provide an answer to the next person to be in the same situation.

To reproduce run `xfce4-screenshooter`, select anything
[image]

and click on `Open with` a program.
[image]

I chose *Gnome Paint Drawing Editor*, but this program also didn't (easily) tell me the location of the file. I failed `save as` but need the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131687/318461) (or [that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/641138/318461)) brought me close to the solution, which is pretty straight-forward: You can enter the command (or anything similar) `cat ~/.config/xfce4/xfce4-screenshooter` to get

```
app=gnome-paint
last_user=
last_extension=png
screenshot_dir=file:/home/cadoiz/temp
enable_imgur_upload=true
action=4
delay=0
region=2
show_mouse=1
show_border=1
```

There, you find `/home/cadoiz/temp` or your path respectively.